# Why Activity keeps extras after orientation change

Tags: android

Let's imagine the `ActivityB` invoked from `ActivityA` with extras in it. When `ActivityB` starts we check in `onCreate()` method the `bundle` holds these extras we put in `ActivityA`. I've noticed that `ActivityB` still holds extras after orientation change, i.e. after `ActivityB` has been just recreated, but not called by `ActivityA` which puts extras in `Intent`. Meaning extras are always "alive"? If I understand this right, where/how Activity keeps it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will find that if onDestroy() is called on your Activity, then the intent will be "reset" and will have no extras, which is what you expect to happen with a rotation change.

To actually remove an extra from an Intent, you need to call [removeExtra(String extra)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#removeExtra%28java.lang.String%29) on the Intent.

If you do not call removeExtra, then yes, the extra will stay in the Intent until the Activity is destroyed.